# Actionscript timestamp string representation

Tags: actionscript

I need to get a string representation of the current timestamp in format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ`

Answer (score 6):

See the [`Date`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) class, and the following properties (in order based on your question):

1. [`fullYear`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#fullYear)
2. [`month`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#month)
3. [`date`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#date)
4. [`hours`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#hours)
5. [`minutes`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#minutes)
6. [`seconds`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#seconds)

---

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var answer:String = date.fullYear + "-" + (date.month+1) + "-" + date.date + " " + date.hours + ":" + date.minutes + ":" + date.seconds;


trace(answer); // 2012-1-17 10:48:41
```